# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion

Tags: objective-c

i am checking if the directory exist but i get a warning

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'BOOL' (aka 'signed
>   char') to parameter of type 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *')

```
 BOOL isFile ;
 isFile = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[dirurl path] isDirectory:YES];
```

why do i get this warning and how to fix it

Comment: From the error is looks like you declared the `isFile` like 'BOOL *isFile;' thus making it a pointer.

Comment: No, it seems, that he needs a pointer instead of a value, which he has now.

Answer (score 9):

Use like this:

```
BOOL isDir;
BOOL isFileExists;

isFileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[dirurl path] isDirectory:&isDir];
if (isDir) {...}
```

Official documentation example [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-CHDBFHAG):

```
NSArray *subpaths;
BOOL isDir;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                     (NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

if ([paths count] == 1) {

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSString *fontPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Fonts"];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fontPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {
        subpaths = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:fontPath];
// ...
[fileManager release];
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  That is such an arcane implementation.  I swear they do things like this to make our lives miserable.